# sqldf : create table from data frame error: "no such table". and two tables created instead of one

Tags: r, sqldf, rsqlite

I've recently upgraded R, RSQLite, and sqldf (versions below).

Normally:

```
sqldf('create table foo as select * from bar', db = 'test.db')
```

should create a table called 'foo' in an attached sqlite database, using data frame 'bar' if it exists to load the new table.

Instead, I'm getting a 'no such table' error, and also when I look at the database there are both 'foo' and 'bar' tables created.

Reproducible example:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(sqldf)
mydb = 'test.db'
## remove file if it exists                                                                                                                                                                                       
system(paste('rm', mydb))
## open connection                                                                                                                                                                                                
##con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname=mydb)                                                                                                                                                                         
system(paste('ls -l', mydb))
sqldf( paste0( 'attach "', mydb, '" as new' ) )
system(paste('ls -l', mydb))
class(mtcars)
sqldf( 'create table mycars as select * from mtcars', dbname = mydb )
sqldf('select * from sqlite_master', dbname = mydb)
sqldf('select * from main.mycars limit 1', dbname = mydb)
sqldf('select * from main.mtcars limit 1', dbname = mydb)
sessionInfo()
```

which produces two tables and throws an error (to add insult to injury):

```
    > library(RSQLite)                                                                                                                                                                                               
     > library(sqldf)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     Loading required package: gsubfn
     Loading required package: proto
     > mydb = 'test.db'                                                                                                                                                                                               
     > ## remove file if it exists                                                                                                                                                                                    
     > system(paste('rm', mydb))                                                                                                                                                                                      
     > ## open connection                                                                                                                                                                                             
     > ##con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname=mydb)                                                                                                                                                                      
     > system(paste('ls -l', mydb))                                                                                                                                                                                   
     ls: test.db: No such file or directory
     > sqldf( paste0( 'attach "', mydb, '" as new' ) )                                                                                                                                                                
     Loading required package: tcltk
     data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
     > system(paste('ls -l', mydb))                                                                                                                                                                                   
     -rwxrwxrwx  1 nathan  staff  1 Jan  6 10:01 test.db
     > class(mtcars)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     [1] "data.frame"
     > sqldf( 'create table mycars as select * from mtcars', dbname = mydb )                                                                                                                                          
     Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) :
       no such table: `mtcars`
     In addition: Warning message:
     Quoted identifiers should have class SQL, use DBI::SQL() if the caller performs the quoting.
     > sqldf('select * from sqlite_master', dbname = mydb)                                                                                                                                                            
        type   name tbl_name rootpage
     1 table mtcars   mtcars        2
     2 table mycars   mycars        5
                                                                                                                                                                                                   sql
     1 CREATE TABLE `mtcars` (\n  "mpg" REAL,\n  "cyl" REAL,\n  "disp" REAL,\n  "hp" REAL,\n  "drat" REAL,\n  "wt" REAL,\n  "qsec" REAL,\n  "vs" REAL,\n  "am" REAL,\n  "gear" REAL,\n  "carb" REAL\n)
     2                          CREATE TABLE mycars(\n  mpg REAL,\n  cyl REAL,\n  disp REAL,\n  hp REAL,\n  drat REAL,\n  wt REAL,\n  qsec REAL,\n  vs REAL,\n  am REAL,\n  gear REAL,\n  carb REAL\n)
     > sqldf('select * from main.mycars limit 1', dbname = mydb)                                                                                                                                                      
       mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
     1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
     > sqldf('select * from main.mtcars limit 1', dbname = mydb)                                                                                                                                                      
       mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
     1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
     > sessionInfo()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
     Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
     Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

     locale:
     [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

     attached base packages:
     [1] tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

     other attached packages:
     [1] sqldf_0.4-10    gsubfn_0.6-6    proto_1.0.0     RSQLite_1.1-1   devtools_1.12.0

     loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] DBI_0.5-1     withr_1.0.2   Rcpp_0.12.8   memoise_1.0.0 digest_0.6.11 chron_2.3-48

Is this a bug or some new intended behavior?  Thanks for your help.
```

Comment: You might be mixing up environments (R vs SQLite). Why not use RSQLite's `dbWriteTable()` and leave `sqldf()` to only manipulate R dfs?

Comment: RSLQite 1.1-1 was recently released and I suspect it has introduced some incompatibility with existing software.  Suggest you downgrade back to RSQLite 1.0.0:  `devtools::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RSQLite/RSQLite_1.0.0.tar.gz")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: `?dbWriteTable` and `?dbRemoveTable` says that `name` is "[a] character string specifying a DBMS table name", it says nowhere that `name` should be quoted, this is what `sqldf` seems to be doing internally. I'd argue that sqldf operates out of spec here. That said, I'm releasing RSQLite 1.1-2 very soon to improve `sqldf` compatibility.

Comment: The last statement before `sessionInfo()` fails also with RSQLite 1.0.0. Please confirm. The following works: `sqldf('select * from mtcars limit 1', dbname = mydb)` .

Comment: I either had to quote them to get it to work with an earlier version of RSQLite or it might have been that this was needed to get it work with all 4 back ends that sqldf supports.  At any rate, `sqldf("select * from mtcars limit 1", dbname = "x.db")` works under RSQLite 1.0.0 whether or not x.db exists but fails in both cases under 1.1-1.  Without `dbname = "x.db"`it works on both RSQLite 1.1-1 and 1.0.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***UPDATE:  newest versions of RSQLite and sqldf do not have the incompatibility issues addressed by this question
i.e.:
sqldf_0.4-10    RSQLite_1.1-2
work together well - Nathan***

All: Thanks to G. Grothendieck for pointers to incompatibility issues introduced by RSQLite 1.1-1.  As stated in the comment to the answer, downgrade RSQLite to 1.0.0:

```
devtools::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RSQLite/RSQLite_1.0.0.tar.gz")
```

Comment: I believe the comment I provided to the question was correct but the above changed the advice and was wrong so I have edited the answer.  You do NOT want to re-install `sqldf` and particularly you do NOT want to install an old version of `sqldf`.  The problem was introduced by RSQLite 1.1-1 and that is the only package you need to roll back.  If you haven't already installed `sqldf` then just install it in the ordinary way using `install.packages("sqldf")` making sure you do it BEFORE you do the above. (Also I have removed the `library(devtools)` line as being redundant.)

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  Installing sqldf after RSQLite will overwrite the 1.0.0 version, which was leading me astray.  Installing the up-to-date sqldf followed by the above install of RSQLite 1.0.0 passes the example test.  Thanks again.

Comment: I opened a related thread here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/372927/16920 to keep strictly RSQLite 1.0.0 in your system because I ofen run into this problem because of updates coming to the system, also updating RSQLite, so breaking the setup once again.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a compatibility problem between the current version of `RSQLite` and the `sqldf` package. `RSQLite` is now stricter about the arguments it accepts for `dbReadTable()`, `dbWriteTable()` and `dbRemoveTable()`, warnings will be issued (but only once per session) until `sqldf` is adapted.

I'll release a compatibility update soon, there is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/issues/196) that will contain progress updates.

Comment: Do you know when it is coming out? I think it is not yet released because I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not.