# Getting warning messages in R after updating sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I just updated all R packages including `sqldf` today. Then I kept getting warning message as follows:

```
Warning message:
Quoted identifiers should have class SQL, use DBI::SQL() if the caller performs the quoting.
```

What is the problem here?
Is this warning serious?
How to fix it?

Update:

This happens after updating `sqldf` and its associated packages. The command I use is `sqldf("select * from something order by something")`

Comment: I can confirm that this occurs in sqldf 0.4-10. To reproduce, try this in a fresh session: `library(sqldf);sqldf("select * from iris limit 1");sqldf("select * from iris limit 1")` You should get the warning the first time, but not the second.

Comment: @sebastian-c Yes, indeed I only got that warning once. My original/real question is whether I should be worried about this.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, but if it worries you - I found rolling back RSQLite removed the warning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41514737/1465387